# Match a specific string only if the entire line doesn't include a specific term

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match all instances of the variable nationFile using a Regex, except when this variable is contained within an import statement. Essentially matching ONLY the string nationFile as long as the entire line does not contain import at the beginning.

I began with this regex but had no luck.

```
(?<!import)nationFile
```

This doesn't work because there might be other text in between import and nationFile, however any attempt I've made seems to include this text in the middle as part of the match, which I do not want.

This solution doesn't work either as lookbehinds need to have a fixed length.

```
(?<!import.*)nationFile
```

Comment: Is it okay to match from the beginning of the line and put your capture in a group? Such as `^(?:(?!import).)*(nationFile)`

Comment: @HaoWu I need to be able to match only the exact string and nothing more in order to run a replace command on that term specifically.

Comment: Non-fixed-width lookbehind *is* possible in JS. On which tool/platform are you using this regex? VSCode?

Comment: Yes, I am using VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution might not be very elegant, but it should work.

Let's say you want to replace `nationFile` with `somethingElse`

If you're using VSCode, it is not possible to use lookbehind with non-fixed width.

But you could capture the whole line using this regex:

```
^((?:(?!import).)*?)nationFile
```

This ensures there's no `import` before encountering `nationFile` from the beginning of the line, then replace it with

```
$1somethingElse
```

The `$1` refers anything between the beginning of the line and `nationFile`. So you could preserve everything before `somethingElse`.

But you might want to search and replace multiple times since it can only capture one instance of `nationFile` each line at a time, until there are no matches left.